# Problems about unscaled graphs in a popped windows

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, graph

I would like to ask if there is anyway to get the graphs frame scaled up in a popped windows using Visual Studio.

For example, if we want to show several graphs at once in a window, I want all the graphs to be seen. What currently happens to me is that the popped window remains fixed and I can't adjust the size to see all the graphs I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking into the `Form.AutoSize` property?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx